# Refreshing inside a route causing 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I'm hosting a website through github pages and I can successfully enter the site. On the landing page I can refresh without any issues, the problem is occuring when i go to http://example.com/about and refresh, which will throw a 404 error. Here are my routes:

```
<div className="App">
  <GlobalProvider>
    <Router basename={'/'}>
      <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'} render={props => <Main {...props} />} />
    </Router>
  </GlobalProvider>
</div>
```

And within  I have two additional routes, one that leads to /about and another one that leads to two different subroutes.

```
<div className="main">
<Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/about'} render={props => <About {...props} aboutData={about} />} />

<Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/cases/:id'} render={props => <CaseOverlay {...props} />} />
</div>
```

It is when i refresh within either of these i get the 404. People with similar problems were told to use the process.env.PUBLIC_URL variable together with the path.

Inside my package.json I set the homepage field to my url which should then change the public_url if I'm not mistaken.

```
 "homepage": "http://example.com",
```

When I log the public_url variable it always seems to be an empty string. I have no idea what is causing this issue anymore since this solution seemed to solve other people exact problem.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Forgot to add that clicking the link to these routes works as intended, but not if i simply enter http://example.com/about directly or refresh while already being on these routes.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages doesn’t support React Router.

There are a [couple of solutions presented here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing):

> - You could switch from using HTML5 history API to routing with hashes ...
> - Alternatively, you can use a trick to teach GitHub Pages to handle 404s ...